# Kohana won't keep Session or Cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, frameworks, kohana

I'm developing a website that makes use of a simple login system.
For some reason it won't keep any of the session or cookie's I'm trying to set.

First I tried setting Sessions using the Kohana method. After that didn't work I resorted to using the standard Session but that didn't work either.

Now I'm trying to set the cookies using `Cookie::set('name', $value);`, but those won't save aswell.

I've checked using a cookie checker and it says there are 0 cookies, but my browser is not set to delete them or any other similar privacy settings.

The bottom of the bootstrap.php file reads:

```
Kohana_Cookie::$salt = md5('supersecretsalt');
Kohana_Cookie::$expiration = 1209600; // 14 days
Kohana_Cookie::$domain = 'theater';
```

I'm working with Kohana 3.3.

I've tried using Chrome, Firefox and Safari, so I'm almost 100% positive it's not caused by the browser.

Am I doing something wrong in the cookie settings?

Comment: Have you set up `application/config/session.php`?

Comment: `Kohana_Cookie::$domain = 'theater';` would be ok for a url like `http://theatre/meow/woof`. Make sure the `Kohana_Cookie::$domain` variable contains the value you would pass as the `domain` parameter to the http://us2.php.net/setcookie function. Since that is exactly how it is used.

Comment: What happens when you replace all `Kohana_Cookie::` with simply `Cookie::`? The `Cookie` class extends `Kohana_Cookie` but I don't have an idea as to what happens with the value of static variables at runtime.

Comment: @user1433479 i need some help what is the time for expiration for one day

Comment: @jacklanza 1209600 is 14 days, so that devided by 14 is 86400.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by replacing the code in bootstrap.php with `Cookie::$salt = 'supersecretsalt';`
Guess what I used was outdated for my version.